# What is the difference between intent and intent filters?Can i declare intent filter in activity instead of manifest?

Tags: android-intent, android-manifest, intentfilter

Please tell us clearly what is intent and intent filter.Can i create intent filter in components instead of declaring in  manifest.Please let us know.

Intent actionIntent=new Intent(action);
        //if(action.matches("ACTION_SEND")){

```
        actionIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,"xxx@gmail.com");

        actionIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "first example");
        actionIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "prepating for interivew-test examples");

        //need this to prompts email client only
        actionIntent.setType("message/rfc821");
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(actionIntent, "Choose an Email client :"));
```

Manifest:

```
        <category android:name = "android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

     </intent-filter>
```

Answer (score 0):

Difference between Intent and Intent filter

Intent are used  to start a new activity . They carry the info from one activity to another if required .In the similar way they are used to start service too .

Intent-filter on the other side tells us the type of component we are about to receive on the basis of  intent's action, data, and category .

No , we cant declare intent-filter other than manifest .

Here is the link for more info  https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters

Comment: Shall we create intent filter programatically?

Comment: Just one question , how can you create intent filter . When they are suppose to be declared in manifest . According to need we can give category , action and data .